# Jetpack Compose how to reverse edge-to-edge when leaving composition

Tags: android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar, android-compose

I want to achieve an edge-to-edge screen (only for a specific screen in the app) and I am using ComponentActivity `enableEdgeToEdge()` method. I want to restore the previous setting when navigating out of this screen. There doesn't seem to be an opposite method to call.

```
    
    @Composable
    fun FullScreen() {
        val context = LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity
    
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            context.enableEdgeToEdge()
            onDispose {
                // context.disableEdgeToEdge() <-- HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS?
            }
        }
    
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 200.dp)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
        ) {
            Text(text = "This is full screen!", style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium)
        }
    }
```

When I press the back button, the previous screen is now edge-to-edge as well, which I do not want.